# Meaning of "Orange is the new black"

Tags: idioms, american-english, spoken-english

There is a TV show by this name. And I heard someone saying it too. I googled its meaning but the effort went in vain.

Comment: Do you understand the idiom [the new black](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+new+black)? That's the first step.

Comment: I think it means *Orange is fashion now* or *Orange is popular now*

Comment: I didn't know this is the idiom. And it all makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: And the point of "orange" is that the show is set in a  prison, where new prisoners must wear orange jumpsuits.

Comment: The name actually comes from a book "Orange is the new black" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Is_the_New_Black:_My_Year_in_a_Women%27s_Prison), which was later turned into the television series.

Answer (score 4):

The expression

> *something* **is the new** *something else*

is a way of expressing **a changeover** when talking about a common property or characteristic of the two *somethings*.

> grey is the new black

refers to the **change** in fashionable colour choice, originally black was very popular and *de rigour*, but for the new season the new colour is grey

> **Orange is the new black**
>   **Orange Is The New Black** (OITNB)

Is the title of an American TV show and a **pun** of sorts. In the storyline a public relations (PR) executive is **sentenced to prison**. Often PR executives may wear **corporate dress** which is **muted and of a dark colour**, usually **black** or near black, a nod to stylish marketing.  In prison, **inmate dress** has been **striped uniforms** to make the prisoners distinctive.  However, nowadays, prisoners will wear **high visibility** clothing so they will be easier to spot.  **Orange** is used extensively in the **US penal system**, for example Guantanamo Bay.  So the title is describing the **transition** of the main character, Piper Chapman, **from corporate workplace to prison cell**.

The title may also be a reference to a *(hoped for)* **change** in sitcoms styles by the producers. Previously there were sitcoms based in the fashion industry, i.e. *Ugly Betty*, where the predominant colour of choice was black, i.e. the [little black dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_black_dress) (LBD). The colour being associated with OITNB is prison **orange**. The title would signify that OITNB would *(like to)* be replacing other sitcoms in the ratings.

Because of the popularity of the show, the use of orange has become more fashionable (the Dutch will appreciate this) causing some prisons to change **inmate dress** back from orange to **stripes**.

Comment: Good answer. For further reading, learners may want to check out [this news article](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/is-60-the-new-40-or-is-40-the-new-60-02-05-2007/), which contains the very related idiom _60 is the new 40_.

Comment: As I wrote above, the phrase is actually the title of a book, which was then turned into a tv series. And as someone approaching 60, I often say that "60 is the new 30".

Comment: "One day you wake up and realize you're not 80 any more" - Walter Matthau, *Grumpy Old Men*