# the meaning of "the new deep" in quote

Tags: phrase-meaning

> Sadly, small talk is the new deep.

This sentence is from [Live Life Happy](https://livelifehappy.com/life-quotes/our-generation-has-lost-the-value-of-romance-the-value-of-trust-the-value-of-conversation-sadly-small-talk-is-the-new-deep/).

What does "the new deep" means? It means "confused talk or unpleasant talk"?

Comment: When *something* is **deep**, it means it has alot of *meaning*, "**deep** thoughts", "**deep** relationships", "**deep** feelings". The phrase construction being used is [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79536/meaning-of-orange-is-the-new-black/79547#79547)

Answer (score 3):

The full quote gives a little more context.

> "Our generation has lost the value of romance, value of trust, the
>   value of conversation, sadly small talk is the new deep.”

[**deep**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deep) has many different usages, but in terms of social interaction, when something is *deep*, it means that it is very meaningful, or not superficial. A similar usage of *deep* in this context is the expression *'deep and meaningful'*, for example.

> I had a deep and meaningful conversation with my girlfriend last
>   night.

...used to describe a conversation of a serious (and probably emotional) nature.

With respect to the sentence construction itself, **X is the new Y** is a common construction used to describe a new trend or fashion overtaking an old one. For example.

> - [Orange is the new Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_Is_the_New_Black)
> - Smart is the new sexy.
> - Healthy is the new skinny.

In the quote you've provided, it seems that the author is trying to say that our generation has lost the ability to communicate at this level, that light or casual conversation (small talk) is as meaningful a conversation we are able to hold. In other words:

> - Small talk is the new deep.